# What are the available methods other than interop to create word document and export data in to that word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have developed a report generating program using interop C#. From my program export data into word documents. Main problem is when i export dataTable into word document (with more than 1000 rows ) which takes longer time to process and export into word document. When i searched i found that interop very slow in large amount of data processing. What are the other methods available other than interop for create word document using C# and export data to it. I cannot use 3rd party libraries to data export (Ex: ItextShart ). Guys need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method [Add tables to word processing documents (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674469%28v=office.15%29.aspx)